# multiple boxplot in subplots in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have 18 individual of np.arrays, each containing 30 numbers with similar range (share = True).

I want to create boxplots for all 18 arrays in a subplot of 1 row, 4 columns. Each subplot will contain few sets of arrays.

How do I do this?

when I try it, it looks like this: [image]

This was my trying to put them in one, the red scratch was what I want it to look like
[image]

Comment: Image link
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j57wu.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe2Iq.png

Answer (score 0):

I get this solved!!

Since it's only 1 row,

I should use only

-axes(num)

instead of

-axes(num,0)